# Python web framework with CRUD powered by AJAX

Tags: python, ajax, crud, web-frameworks, turbogears

I am looking for a Python web framework which will allow me to rapidly build a CRUD application with automatic AJAX support.

The framework should be able to generate a nice table which is sortable and filterable, which works via AJAX and without JS support at all as well.

I have looked at TurboGears2 and it seems promising, is there any other framework that can do the job for me?

Answer (score 6):

Most of the modern frameworks, like TG, Django or Flask support CRUD-style applications. But none of those are that much abstract, that you can give them a model, and there you have your ajaxy db manipulation templates and validations.

Django has *django-admin* and a great form builder and helper module; Flask can work with WTForms easily. Javascript is just as usable with any of the above frameworks, so that with a little recherche in the jQuery plugin area, you might be able to quickly build your application.

Comment: I am familiar with Django-admin, but it is only for simple admin stuff, I don't want to spend time hacking Django-admin, that is not its purpose, it would be much easier to write the app using django-filter. And also I do not want to hand code JS everytime if there are other frameworks which can do this simple task for me.

Answer (score 6):

You might check out [web2py](http://www.web2py.com). Very easy [CRUD](http://web2py.com/book/default/chapter/07#CRUD), and great [Ajax support](http://web2py.com/book/default/chapter/10) (see also, web2py [components](http://web2py.com/book/default/chapter/13#Components)). web2py's [`plugin_wiki`](http://web2py.com/book/default/chapter/13#plugin_wiki) also includes [widgets](http://web2py.com/book/default/chapter/13#Current-Widgets) for CRUD and [jqGrid](http://www.trirand.com/blog).

There's also a new grid plugin under development called [powerTable](http://powertable.blouweb.com), which is a web2py wrapper for the jQuery [DataTables](http://datatables.net) plugin.

If you have questions, the [web2py community](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/web2py) will be happy to help you out.

Comment: thanks, I will maybe have a look at web2py, I am currently checking TurboGears2 with Sprox which can generate all the CRUD stuff with AJAX.

Comment: powerTable looks really impressive

Comment: I don't know much about TurboGears, but note that they have decided to merge with the Pylons Project (I think the plan is to continue to maintain TurboGears, but also to focus on adding "full stack" tools on top of the new Pyramid framework). See http://groups.google.com/group/turbogears/browse_frm/thread/a6ef71ebea4ebcb0.

Comment: TuboGears is a meta framework it is built on top of other projects, yes it uses Pylons, TG1 used CherryPy

Comment: @denysonique, yes TG2 is built on top of Pylons. What I was saying is that the TG team is planning to merge with the newly formed Pylons Project and start building a new set of full stack tools on top of the new Pyramid framework (which is a merger of Pylons and repoze.bfg). I assume they will maintain TG2 for some time, but presumably it will ultimately be superceded by whatever they end up building on top of Pyramid.